# Median.test error 'x' and 'y' are not the same length

Tags: r, statistics

I've already measured the length of the variable that Im testing, but im still getting error although the length of each variable are the same

```
library("agricolae")

#meausre length
length(df$X2019_Perkotaan.Perdesaan)
length(df$X2020Perkotaan.Perdesaan)

Median.test(df$X2019_Perkotaan.Perdesaan, df$X2020Perkotaan.Perdesaan)
```

and the output

```
[1] 34

[1] 34

Error in chisq.test(B, correct, simulate.p.value) :
'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

I've also tried re-arrange the variable into a list like:

```
x <- c(65,69,70,76,71,66,67,69,75,88,93,78,67,31)
y <- c(72,74,75,81,76,75,72,74,78,91,93,82,80,35)
```

but the output still the same with:

```
[1] 34

[1] 34

Error in chisq.test(B, correct, simulate.p.value) :
'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

does anyone how I can fix it and make it work?

Comment: The documentation for `agricolae::Median.test()` says that it wants `Variable response` and `Treatments`. Is that what you're providing in `df$X2019_Perkotaan.Perdesaan` and `df$X2020Perkotaan.Perdesaan`?

Comment: Oh yeah i'm sorry, I forgot to mention about the treatment variable for the Median.test()

I don't what should I input for the treatment variable so I figure putting the y variable  as the treatment variable. 

If the treatment what causes the error, what should I Input for the input variable? I still don't understood the uses for the treatment variable

Comment: Is `Median.test` definitely the test you want to run? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Without knowing more about your data, the following is just a guess.

`Median.test` assesses groups of data to see if they're members of the same population. The code below generates some sample data in three different groups. The first two groups have the same mean and the same standard deviation - they are effectively from the same population. The third group has a different mean - it's from a different population. We graph these data to visualise these populations. You can see that groups A & B look pretty similar, whereas group C is a lot higher.

The `Median.test` test confirms this. It assigns our groups A & B to the same group (b) and our group C to a separate group (a). This tells us that our groups A & B are not significantly different from each other, but they are significantly different from our group C.

```
library('dplyr')

tempDF <- data.frame(group = 'A', value = rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=1)) %>%
  bind_rows(data.frame(group = 'B', value = rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=1))) %>%
  bind_rows(data.frame(group = 'C', value = rnorm(100, mean=20, sd=1))) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(group))
            
tempDF[c(1:3, 101:103, 201:203), ]
#     group     value
# 1       A  9.689846
# 2       A  9.888977
# 3       A 10.561062
# 101     B 10.615753
# 102     B 10.813653
# 103     B 10.802487
# 201     C 20.722176
# 202     C 20.024502
# 203     C 21.755496

ggplot(tempDF) +
  geom_jitter(aes(y=value, x=group, col=group))
```

[image]

```
library("agricolae")
agricolae::Median.test(tempDF$value, tempDF$group)

# The Median Test for tempDF$value ~ tempDF$group 
# 
# Chi Square = 151.28   DF = 2   P.Value 1.412425e-33
# Median = 10.74547 
# 
#     Median   r       Min      Max       Q25      Q75
# A 10.21477 100  7.523782 12.73195  9.373418 10.89216
# B 10.21126 100  7.449177 12.59683  9.342479 10.64383
# C 20.06727 100 17.316426 22.45921 19.249686 20.67125
# 
# Post Hoc Analysis
# 
# Groups according to probability of treatment differences and alpha level.
# 
# Treatments with the same letter are not significantly different.
# 
#   tempDF$value groups
# C     20.06727      a
# A     10.21477      b
# B     10.21126      b
```

Comment: Oh I Understand now thank you so much! I might have choose the wrong data sample for the `trt` variable and that's why the test won't work.  I guess the `trt` variable needs to be ordinal in order for the test to work. 




the variable `df$X2019_Perkotaan.Perdesaan` and `df$X2020Perkotaan.Perdesaan` presents the percentage of internet users in households from rural + city area by each provinces in Indonesia from the year 2019 and 2020, and both are ratio data by definition.  I should have put provinces grouped by region as the `trt`  instead of  `df$X2020Perkotaan.Perdesaan`.

Comment: and again thank you so much! your explanation was really helpful